# Engagement Index in civicrm Activities Section

Tags: activity

Does anyone know the use of the civicrm engagement index?

Thanks in advance

Edward

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/civic-engagement/what-you-need-to-know/), it's "to gauge their level of interest or potential to be a highly active member or be easily mobilised for direct actions".

If you use a methodology that involves an [engagement ladder](http://www.idealware.org/articles/engagement-pyramid-six-levels-connecting-people-and-social-change), you can decide that signing an online petition is an index of 1, showing up in person to a rally is an index of 2, recruiting others to attend is an index of 3, etc.  Then you can use CiviCRM to find users who have taken an action of a certain level or higher.  This is also potentially useful to fundraisers who use moves management/donor journeys.

Comment: Could you include instructions for how to find people who have taken action of a "certain level or higher"? I cannot see that functionality in Advanced Search - I just have to select one particular level. Also, it probably doesn't matter and I think your logic makes more sense, but according to [the docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/campaign/set-up/) "1 is a high level of engagement, and 5 is low level of engagement."